# PyDev - unresolved import only on IDE, still running

Tags: python, pydev

I'm trying to understand what PyDev doesn't like. I'm under Ubuntu and it seems that PyDev doesn't see the libraries like bash does.
I have a problem with two libraries, sqlite3 and peewee. If I run my program on a shell, all fine; if I open it in my newly installed PyDev I see a couple of instruction underlined with the message

> Unresolved import: sqlite3

And

> Undefined variable from import: get

The first error comes from the following code:

```
from pprint import pprint
import sqlite3
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import codecs
from database import Tbrecipe
from datetime import datetime
import logging

def main():
    logger = logging.getLogger('peewee')
    logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
    logger.addHandler(logging.StreamHandler())
    CONN = sqlite3.connect('ent.db')
```

The import error happens at the.. import. Second line.This happens because I've personally added /usr/lib/python2.7/sqlite3 to the pythonpath on the pydev's python interpreter. If I remove it, the error is at "sqlite3.connect". I suppose connect is not defined on that directory. I didn't find it.

Peewee has other issues. I created an object class for my database's table. All fine until I try to use some methods inherited from peewee.

My database.py looks like this:

from peewee import *
database = MySQLDatabase('test', **{'host': 'localhost',
 'password': 'rt', 'user': 'rt','charset':'utf8mb4'})

class UnknownField(object):
    def **init**(self, *_, **__): pass

class BaseModel(Model):
    class Meta:
        database = database

class Tbitem(BaseModel):
    source = IntegerField()
    name = CharField(null=True)

on my main.py

```
...
from database import Tbitem
item = Tbitem.get(Tbitem.id==id_item)
```

both "get" and "Tbitem.id" are underlined in red with the error

> Undefined variable from import: get

I can continue to work as nothing happens, or I can go back to vim or vscode (slow debugger), but I"d prefer using this since I'm used to eclipse and I like the idea of pydev. What should I do? I did check pythonpath on a shell and it looks the same, other than a directory that doesn't exist anymore.

I read on the FAQ of pydev that it doesn't like softlinks. Should I remove all softlinks? peewee is not softlinked and sqlite3 I don't even know where it finish.

Anyone with similar issues and a solution? I did read most of the questions here on SO, but they don't work for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by forcing the build of all external libraries that caused that error (force builtins under interpreter's properties)
For my libraries I deleted all .pyc files and tried again and it worked.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue with Orange-Bioinformatics, code would run fine but PyDev showed an unknown import.

The problem in this case were missing `__init__.py` files in the Orange-Bioinformatics archive, which pip downloaded and installed. PyDev seems to want a namespace declaration for each module, so I simply created a file in ~/.local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/orangecontrib/ (would be /usr/lib/python2.7/sqlite3/ in your case), named the file `__init__.py` and saved it with the following content:

```
# namespace stub
__import__("pkg_resources").declare_namespace(__name__)
```

The file was put into the subfolder orangecontrib/bio/

Just refresh PyDev's module list via Window -> Preferences -> PyDev -> Interpreters -> Python Interpreter -> Apply. Now all works well for me :-)

Answer (score 0):

Bonjour,

As you, I had an unresolved import only on IDE and I found a workaround.

I installed "netifaces" using the appropriate command :

```
pip3 install netifaces
```

After the installation, I got two entries in the folder "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages"  (ref. Mac OS + homebrew).

- netifaces-0.10.6.dist-info
- netifaces.cpython-36m-darwin.so

At this point, I had an unresolved import issue in the PyDev editor, but my application runs well when I launched it using a Pydev launch configuration and the same interpreter.

Note: I also import other modudes installed using pip3 and their importations did'nt generate issue.

I created the symbolic link "netifaces.so" to get the same file I found in the "site-packages" folder of the Python 2.7.13 interpretor

```
ln -s  netifaces.cpython-36m-darwin.so  netifaces.so
```

After this creation, all run well : the import issues desapear in the Pydev editor.

Question : where is the error ?

1. In the module installation done by pip3 : the installed ".so" file doesn't have the name of the module ?
2. In the module discovery function of pyDev which doesn't take care of the "platform extended" name of the installed ".so" file

Comment: I didn't have the time to test it yet, but I think I will try the "force builtins". for all libraries that gives me similar issues